# Add Atom Link in REST Service

Tags: c#, rest, atom-feed

I am creating a REST Service using .Net 4.0 and MVC4 and I want to provide atom link for the other resources in the method response.

So Response should look like:

```
<Customers xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <atom:link rel="self" href="/customers"/>
  <Customer>
    <atom:link rel="self" href="/customers/101"/>
    <Id>101</Id>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I would like to know how can we add atom links?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do **Content negotiation:**

Web API has built-in support for content negotiation – which enables the client and server to work together to determine the right format for data being returned from an API.  We provide default support for JSON, XML and Form URL-encoded formats, and you can extend this support by adding your own formatters, or even replace the default content negotiation strategy with one of your own.

Here is how to add a JSON formatter. You would have to add and ATOM one. The link would need to be somewhere on your model.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx